# Objective-C Array Index Wrap

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode7

I'm wondering if it is possible to wrap a Array in Objective-C

Example:

I have an Array called `characters` that contains the alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Being the alphabet, it only contains `26` characters.

I would like to be able to get the `objectAtIndex` of say `30`, however it returns `beyond bounds` (understandable).

```
NSString *letter = [characters objectAtIndex:30];
```

What I would like is the Array to wrap around. Example, the `objectAtIndex` of `30` to return `d`, the 4th Character as it wraps from last character to the first.

Here is the specific line from my code:

```
NSString *encoded = [characters objectAtIndex:[characters indexOfObject:chars] + keyNumber % [characters count]];
```

The variables change depending on other instances, so the `objectAtIndex` will vary.

Thank you your time is much appreciated. Any queries please ask.

James Noon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a pair of parentheses:

```
[characters objectAtIndex:([characters indexOfObject:chars] + keyNumber) % characters.count];
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping is often done using the modulo operator:

```
NSString *letter = characters[index % 26];
//                                  ^
```

However better might be:

```
NSString *characters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
unichar letter = [characters characterAtIndex:index % 26];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a category for `NSArray` and add your own method for `objectAtIndex:` that takes the index and finds the modulo of the length of the array and then returns the object at that index. Adding a log whenever the given index is greater than the array length would be helpful as well or when the array has a length of 0.

But, I would recommend creating a separate method in that category just for finding the wrapped index and calling it something like `objectAtWrappedIndex:`.